# Why laravel broadcast channel has default prefix?

Tags: laravel, react-native, pusher

currently i am working on a mobile application using react native, and as back end i am using Laravel.

As  a channels client library at the client side i am using [Pusher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js)

This is how my channel route looks like in the back end

```
Broadcast::channel('conversation.{message_id}', function ($user,$id) {
    return true;
});
```

I can broadcast successfully, but at pusher debug console i've noticed that a prefix (private-) added to the route.

[image]
Here is how i listen to event

```
                const pusher = new Pusher('XXXX', {
                    cluster: 'eu',
                    authEndpoint: 'http:backend.test/api/broadcasting/auth',
                    auth: {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer `+token,
                            Accept: 'application/json',
                        },
                    },
                });
                const channel = pusher.subscribe('private-conversation.7');
                channel.bind('App\\Events\\MessageSent', function (data) {
                    console.log("event")
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

As you can see in my code i subscribe to "private-conversation.7", pusher debug console shows that the client is subscribed to channel successfully, but the issue is that the client didn't listen to events, when i create a custom event in pusher and set "conversation.7" as a channel name (i removed private- prefix) the event triggered with success.

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

That is a convention used to separate private, public and presence channel.

When you subscribe a channel with `private-` prefix, it will require the auth process.

Laravel will automatically add `private-` prefix to channel name when broadcast.

```php
/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('orders.'.$this->order->id);
}
```

Here are reference docs:

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/private-channels